# Change Version and MSI and Have the Version Info Reflect In file Properties Advanced Installer

Tags: windows, advanced-installer

I am creating an msi with Advanced Installer 11.4.1

I see the Product Version in AI, but it doesnt show up anywhere in file properties. (see orca image)

[image]

I also tried to Set Version using the command line

```
"%AI%" /edit "%TEMP_MSI%\setup.aip" /SetVersion 1.2.23
```

The Version seems to get set but its not available in the msi's file properties

[image]

Even if I could get the Version to show up in the Comments field that'd be great.

Or maybe the property in Details property is hidden and needs to be visible?

Comment: I would just put the version number into the file name? That has some consequence that you can't use minor upgrades though (many don't use them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you need to edit the **MSI metadata**, while now you've changed the [ProductVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion) which is an MSI property.

To edit the MSI metadata, you need to go in the **Builds view** and at the bottom page from the **Configuration** tab you will see the **Database encoding** section. Expand it to have access to the [Customize Summary Information](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/customize-summary-information-dialog.html).